# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{in}}{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

How to analyze the  convergence of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{in}}{n}$$ ?

Which test should I use?

I'm lost in this topics. Any hint/help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Dirichlet's test as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), take $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n = e^{in}$. Then check the required conditions for the series $\sum a_nb_n$ to converge.

$$a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{n} = a_n$$
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0$$
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N} b_n\right| = \left|\sum_{n=1}^{N} e^{in}\right| \leq \left|\frac{1}{\sin(1/2)}\right| = M$$

The answer uses $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}e^{in} = e^{i(N-1)/2}\frac{\sin(N/2)}{sin(1/2)}$ as shown in the answer by @Salahamam_Fatima.

Comment: I understand now, thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

**hint**

$$e^{in}=\cos (n)+i\sin (n) $$

with  Dirichlet test for
$$\sum \frac {\cos (n)}{n} $$and
$$\sum \frac {\sin (n)}{n} $$
using
$$e^i+e^{2i}+...e^{ni}=$$
$$e^{i(n-1)/2}\frac {\sin (n/2)}{\sin (1/2)} $$

Comment: and how do I find a bound for $|sin(1)+sin(2)+...+sin(n)|$ ?

Comment: @AnneliseToft Take imaginary part of geometric series $e^i+e^{2i}+e^{3i}+...e^{ni} $.

Comment: But first why do I have to apply Dirichlet test just for $cos(n)/n$?

Comment: @AnneliseToft for both by the same.

Comment: I think I finally understand , $a_n=1/n$ in both cases and $b_n=cos(n)$ (or $b_n=sin(n)$ ). Also the bound M for $|b_1+...+b_n|$ is $M=Re( e^{i(n-1)/2}\frac {\sin (n/2)}{\sin (1/2)})$ (or for $b_n=sin(n)$ is $Im(M)$ ). Am I correct?

Comment: $\left|e^{i\frac{n-1}{2}}\frac{\sin(\frac{n}{2})}{\sin(\frac{1}{2})}\right| = \left|\frac{\sin(\frac{n}{2})}{\sin(\frac{1}{2})}\right| \leq \left|\frac{1}{\sin(\frac{1}{2})}\right|$ which is the bound M (a constant).

Comment: Oh I haven't notice it, thanks @expiTTp1z0

Comment: is the bound M for both $|sin(1)+sin(2)+...+sin(n)|$ and $|cos(1)+cos(2)+...+cos(n)|$, right? @expiTTp1z0

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: Dirichlet test is incorrectly applied in this answer, however, the answer surely presented the core idea for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply with $1-e^i\ne 0$ to get the series
$$
e^i-\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{e^{in}}{n(n-1)}
$$
which is absolutely convergent.

In principle this is the direct application of the proof method of the Dirichlet test.